# Group by the same ID with diferent diseases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

[image: Like this]

each different disease create a new row with the same ID, i want to group this rows to transform the ID into a primary key. I already tried a bunch of queryes without success.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I already try group by, without success. Can't group by different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With group by you can group by data with a column. Here you want to group by your `ID` and keep the maximum of every ID. So you can use `GROUP BY` and display the maximum value with `MAX()`.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DISEASE1), MAX(DISEASE2), MAX(DISEASE3)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```